# Java : Are there non-Oracle implementations of Java standard classes?

Tags: java

As far as I understand, anyone can implement a JVM (Java Virtual Machine) that conforms to the [JVM specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/). However, when it comes to the standard Java library (e.g. classes like `String`, `ArrayList`, etc.), are compilers allowed to re-implement these classes, or any JDK *has* to use the implementations provided by Oracle? If third-party implementations are allowed, can anyone please point to a few of these because I have searched the Internet a lot and haven't found any answer yet.

I am new to the Java ecosystem have a long C++ background. In C++, the [Standard Template Library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/standard_library) is standarised as part of the C++ standard and every compiler implements its own version. However, I have failed to find a similar standard for Java library classes. There is, of course, the [Oracle API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/index.html) but it doesn't really compare with the detailed specification C++ provides.

Comment: [Here is the API specification](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/index.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are, though these are nowadays less frequently used because of the free availability of OpenJDK SDK (which includes JVM, JRE, Java Class libraries (JCL), and everything).

A notable project was [Apache Harmony](https://harmony.apache.org/subcomponents/classlibrary/) which had implementations for almost all classes available in Java SE 5.0. It had implemented 99% of Java SE 5 classes and about 97% of Java SE 6. Link [here](http://people.apache.org/%7Ehindessm/japi/).

Apache Harmony could run several large projects including Eclipse, and TomCat, among others. Also, Android was based on classes from this project.

GNU had their project, [GNU Class Path](https://www.gnu.org/software/classpath/). It states implementing >95% of classes for Java up to version 6.

IBM also provides its own full [Java implementations](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/java-sdk/) as a complete replacement for what Oracle is attempting to serve. IBM implementations are used mainly on their Z/OS-based mainframes.

There were/are several JCL implementations. Now that OpenJDK is freely available there is less incentive in using alternates. Android started using OpenJDK JCL. When Java was not free, there were more efforts towards non-Oracle JVMs, JREs, and JCLs (which are bundled together to make the JDK)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a *standardization* of the framework classes.

For example, the *[OpenJDK](https://openjdk.org/)* utilizes proposals for implementing new, and deprecating old, logic.
You can review a template, here.  *[OpenJDK – JEP 2: JEP Template](https://openjdk.org/jeps/2)*.

If it were a standardization, there would be a more formal process.

As *@andrewJames* mentioned in the comments, there is also the *[Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/index.html)*, which, at the least, provides a specification on this topic.

*[1.4. Relationship to Predefined Classes and Interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-1.html#jls-1.4)*.

> *"... In particular, some classes and interfaces have a special relationship with the Java programming language. Examples include classes such as Object, Class, ClassLoader, String, and Thread, and the classes and interfaces in the package java.lang.reflect, among others. This specification constrains the behavior of such classes and interfaces, but does not provide a complete specification for them. The reader is referred to the Java SE Platform API documentation. ..."*

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into GNU Classpath? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Classpath

This is the only other complete implementation of the java std lib that I am aware of, although there definitely may be more out there. I am not sure if each JDK (OpenJDK, Coretto, etc) has their own libraries, but this seems to answer your question whether or not each one is required to implement Oracles std lib.

EDIT: 30 min wait time to answer, I missed it and someone already mentioned this and gave a far better answer.